# How to change object from any environment?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to modify some code (or add / delete) in the environment where this code lives. I have found this topic really helpful: [How to change on the fly a line of an existing function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260840/how-to-change-on-the-fly-a-line-of-an-existing-function-in-r), but problem I have is that function I want to modify is not in the `.GlobalEnv` and I don't know what is the name of this environment.

This environment I'm thinking about could be described as a `B` environment from this answer on one of my previous question: [What is an environment where exists all objects from all files sourced when running Shiny App?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70490294/13032723). So basically I would like to change some code in Shiny App. I managed to find the environment using `environment()` function, but I see I can't replace the code.

Perhaps my problem can be shown using this code:

```
test <- function() 1

test()
#> [1] 1

environment(test)$test <- eval(parse(text = "function() 2"))

test()
#> [1] 1

.GlobalEnv$test <- eval(parse(text = "function() 3"))

test()
#> [1] 3
```

How can I make this line of code: `environment(test)$test <- eval(parse(text = "function() 2"))` to work? i.e. how to change the object using `environment()`?

@jpiversen let me kindly note you about this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with using test multiple times on the left hand side confusing `$<-` in "R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)" and presumably other versions of R as well.

**1)** A workaround would be to break the assignment into two statements.

```
test <- function() 1

test()
## [1] 1

e <- environment(test)
e$test <- eval(parse(text = "function() 2"))

test()
## [1] 2
```

**2)** Alternately use `assign`

```
test <- function() 1

test()
## [1] 1

assign("test", eval(parse(text = "function() 2")), environment(test))

test()
## [1] 2
```

### Note

1. The examples work the same if we use `function() 1` and `function() 2` in place of `eval(parse(text = "function() 1"))` and `eval(parse(text = "function() 2"))` .
2. This question or variations of it was also posted on [r-help](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2021-December/473425.html) and [r-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2021-December/081402.html) and [r-bugs](https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18269) and in the last one Luke Tierney indicated that this is due to the way $<- works with environments (see that link for detailed explanation) but the bottom line is that they feel it would be too disruptive to show a warning or error or to change it at this point.

Comment: Thank you this detailed answer :)